# variable that be change after some code RSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable like this:

```
var a=$('#div2').html();
```

after some code div be changed, so 'a' be changed too, but i want first value of 'a'.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't overwrite your `a` variable?

Comment: If you change the html of this div your variable will not change.

Comment: no... my codes are in $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: when are you changing variable value again in your code? on change of html of div2, variable will not change its value until you assign it seperately.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
      <div id="div2"> Sample </div>
      <input type="button" onclick="change();" value="change" />
```

SCRIPT:

```
     <script>
        var a = $('#div2').html();
        function change() {

            $('#div2').html('Change');
            var previous = a;
            a = $('#div2').html();
            alert(previous);
        }
    </script>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fmqszcu3/)